# new at phonegap/cordova (Many doubts)

Tags: android, apache, cordova

I recently started to investigate the development of applications with Apache Cordoba after installing Phonegap. I have some doubts that after spending hours surfing the official page of apache and phonegap and view multiple tutorials still unresolved and would like to know if anyone can clarify.

As I've understood Apache Cordova allows you to develop hybrid applications from web applications.
My question is that as I found in the official documentation, with Apache console once you have added the different platforms you want to develop for using the command

```
platform Cordova add <platform name>
```

then you can run the application for your platform with the command  `Cordova run <platform name>`

What I don't have very clear is the file structure. For example, assuming you have created a project called HelloWorld, in the project folder, you will find a folder called www, which contains the following files

```
www/
├── css
│   └── index.css
├── img
│   └── logo.png
├── index.html
└── js
└── index.js
```

and if you have added the Android platform, in the directory  HelloWorld/platforms/android/assets there is a folder called www that has the following structure:

```
www/
├── cordova.js
├── cordova-js-src
│   ├── android
│   │   ├── nativeapiprovider.js
│   │   └── promptbasednativeapi.js
│   ├── exec.js
│   ├── platform.js
│   └── plugin
│   └── android
│   └── app.js
├── cordova_plugins.js
├── css
│   └── index.css
├── img
│   └── logo.png
├── index.html
├── js
│   └── index.js
└── plugins
├── cordova-plugin-vibration
│   └── www
│   └── vibration.js
└── cordova-plugin-whitelist
└── whitelist.js
```

Until the moment I've imported the project in Android Studio and I've compiled it so as to generate the apk, modifying the files that are located in the folder HelloWorld/platforms/android/assets/www .

But my doubt is, in case that you want to export the aplication to multiple platforms, should I have to edit the files of the folder HelloWorld/www ? 
If it's not the case, I understand that we're not making an only project for all the platforms.

I don't know if there's a tutorial that explains these differences, cause even that I've searching many pages I don't get it. My goal by now is to test some plugins that offers apache to access to the device hardware, as could be the vibration or the camera with simple applications.

I would be grateful if someone could clarify these doubts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be modifying the files in HelloWorld/www directory to begin with. When you build for a platform (which is something that happens when you use the "cordova run " command, it copies your files over to the correct platform's assets directory and builds the APK or other package type from there. I'm a little suprised it isn't wiping out your changes with the content from HelloWorld/www.

Answer (score 0):

As MHardwick wrote, the cordova way is, that you develope in the root www-folder and then you start cordova run, which copies all the files to the platform www folders.

I don't like this way. In my root www folder I have the index.html file and an asset folder. In this folder I have all the js/css/images/… files.

In Android I use a symlink from the index.html file and root asset folder to the android www folder. In iOS I use a precompile script in Xcode, which does the some link.

**Attention:** If you are going this way, don't copy the whole www folder in root to the platforms. In the platforms www folder a platform depending files.